# am using next tsx and i want my hamburger menu pop to go off whereever i click on the main page how do i do that

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

```
'use client'
import beardman from '@/public/beardman2.svg'
import Image from 'next/image'
import Menu from '@/public/menu-bar.png'
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link'
import {usePathname } from 'next/navigation'

export default function Navbar(){
  
  const[isMenu, setIsMenu] = useState(false)
  const pathname = usePathname()

  const toggleMenu=()=>{
    setIsMenu(!isMenu)
  }

  useEffect(()=>{
  if(pathname==='/whychooseus' || pathname==='/beautytips')
    setIsMenu(false)
  },[])

    return(
        <div className='navbar flex justify-between m-2 border-black border-1 font-cursive'> 
          <div className="mt-0">
             <Image src={beardman} width={74} height={75} alt='beardman'/>
          </div>
          <div className='Alex Brush p-2 text-5xl font-bold'>
            <h1>Face 2 Face</h1>
          </div>
          <div className='max-lg:hidden flex justify-between mx-2 mt-6 text-xl space-x-16'>
              <Link href='/' className='nav-items'>Home</Link>
              <Link href='/whychooseus' className='nav-items'>why choose us</Link>
              <Link href='/beautytips' className='nav-items'>beauty tips</Link>
          </div>
          <div className='mt-3 hidden max-lg:block'>
            <Image src={Menu} width={48} height={47} alt='Menu' id='menu-bar' onClick={toggleMenu} />
                {isMenu && ( 
                  <div className='menu-popup'>
                    <Link href='/' className='nav-items'>Home</Link>
                    <Link href='/whychooseus' className='nav-items'>why choose us</Link>
                    <Link href='/beautytips' className='nav-items'>beauty tips</Link>
                  </div>
                )}
          </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

so the above code shows page and in the mobile size window, hamburger menu shows and when i click on the hamburger menu bar pops up, when i click on the hamburger menu, menu bar goes off i want to make where ever i click on the screen i want my menu bar to go off